# What is the correct way to run execute_script with selenium Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, discord

I want to automatically log in to Discord using a JS code that needs to be pasted into the browser console. I'm just learning Python and have absolutely no knowledge of JS. Here is the code to paste into the console:

```
function login(token) {
    setInterval(() => {
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(() => {
      location.reload();
    }, 2500);
  }

login(token);
```

Here is my failed attempt:

```
token = 'token'
driver.execute_script('return function login(token) {setInterval(() => {document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`}, 50);setTimeout(() => {location.reload();}, 2500);}login('+"'"+f'{token}'+"');")
```

Received an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected identifier 'login'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
token = 'token'

js = 'function login(token) {setInterval(() => {document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`}, 50);setTimeout(() => {location.reload();}, 500);}'
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script(js + f'login("{token}")')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).